# How can I make my blade material more realistic?

Tags: materials, edges, photorealism

How can I highlight the edges and overall make the sword's blade more realistic?
I'm trying to make a game asset
[image]
[image]

Edit: I removed the normal map, made the edges thicker, and lowered the roughness. I apologize if I don't understand everything, I'm kinda new here.
[image]
[image]
Also this is the handle/leather material
[image]
And finally here is the pommel and guard configuration
[image]
[image]

Comment: since you didn't show us any of your material nodes/settings it's a bit hard. Generally i would use higher metallic value and less roughness.

Comment: As Chris says, put the Metallic value at 1 (between 0 and 1 is not realistic), lower down the Roughness, also make sure that the material has something to reflect so give your world an HDRI if it's not already the case. As for the edge, give it a bit of thickness? But maybe share your file so we can try (only share the blade, and pack the HDRI image if there's one): https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: ...And you might want to reverse the normal map, because it looks like it's pointing in the wrong direction.

Comment: Anisotropic to give the blade a grain?

Comment: Well, could you attach something you want it to look like? Also, try using cycles render engine instead of eevee

Comment: The *Color Space* of the *Image Texture* nodes ("*cross norms*", "*pommel norms*") that are connected to the *Normal Map* nodes should be *Non-Color* instead of *sRGB*.